# How to get generated key from INSERT with camel-sql or camel-jdbc

Tags: apache-camel

I am try to get the generated key from a insert. But I got an `oracle.sql.ROWID`.

```xml
<route id="myroute">
  <from uri="direct:myroute" />
  <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelSqlRetrieveGeneratedKeys">
    <simple>true</simple>
  </camel:setHeader>
  <to uri="sql-db:{{myquery}}"/>
</route>
```

My SQL:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, name, description) VALUES(MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, :#NAME, :#DESCRIPTION)
```

But a receive a `oracle.sql.ROWID`. My Headers values:

```
{CamelSqlGeneratedKeyRows=[{ROWID=oracle.sql.ROWID@4e9adff2}], breadcrumbId=ID-VAIO-17584-1456233791521-0-9 ...
```

The ROWID is not number...it's address from row :( with value `AABNPdAAOAAC0AOAAB`.

So, how to get the generated key (sequence value) with camel-sql?

I have to use

> select MY_SEQUENCE.currval from dual

? :(

thanks.

`Camel 2.16.2`
`Spring 4.1.5`
`JDK 1.7-1.8`
`Oracle 11g`

Answer (score 0):

The return is basically the preparedStatment return with Statement. RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS as one more parameter which enables to retrieve the generated keys.Can you run your query with plain Java.sql prepared statement and check what is happening there. You should be able to get the details without the second query.